# How to optimizer embedding_lookup_sparse in TensorFlow for cached data?

Tags: caching, optimization, tensorflow, embedding, inference

TensorFlow is great and we have implemented the neural network models for recommend system. We use `embedding_lookup_sparse` to handle the sparse inputs. Then export the models with `SavedModel` APIs and serve with `TensorFlow Serving`. Everything works well but we think we can optimizer the process for our dataset.

Here is our typical dataset. All the features can be divided into two parts, "user features" and "item features". Each batch has multiple samples which are from the same user, so these samples have the same "user features".

For example, here is a batch of 5 samples and the top 100 features are "user features".

```
label    user features          item features
1      2:1 15:1 30:1 70:1     110:1 190:1 200:1
0      2:1 15:1 30:1 70:1     170:1 290:1 300:1
1      2:1 15:1 30:1 70:1     180:1 390:1 400:1
1      2:1 15:1 30:1 70:1     190:1 490:1 500:1
0      2:1 15:1 30:1 70:1     200:1 590:1 600:1
```

Because the "user features" are always the same for each batch, we don't need to "lookup" for the complete matrix but only the first one sample.

We have implemented this optimization for cached data in Java and got almost four times speedup. But we want to use `TensorFlow Serving` to serve the models so we may need to implement the "optimized embedding_lookup_sparse" as TensorFlow op.

This format of dataset is really common in recommend system and the performance of inference would be improved greatly with this optimization. Could anyone help or indicate how to implement this in `TensorFlow`?

BTW, the "item features" can be cached globally as well. It's another way to optimizer.